# How to format time and date from a recordset?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a dynamic table that displays a list of records with their date and time. The date and time displays correctly, but when I move to a hosting server, I get a different date and time, which I know is based on its timezone. I have seen different tutorials showing how to format date and time in different timezone when it is echoed on a page, but when I try it with my binded data from my recordset, it doesn't work online.

This is my binded recordset data:

`<?php echo $row_forum['Date']; ?>`

Please explain to me: "How to format for Africa/Lagos?".

Comment: post whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: @krupal shah I edited his answer and made code visible.

Comment: @vasili111 ok..thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Ok lets assume your server is in London and you want to know the time as it was in Lagos when the timestamp was created.

You need to use the handy DateTime class. [Manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

```
<?php
// assume this is when the row was created on the server in london.
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01 01:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Europe/london'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

// Now you want to print the time that it was in Lagos when the row was created.
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Africa/Lagos'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

The output would be

```
2000-01-01 01:00:00+00:00
2000-01-01 02:00:00+01:00
```

One hour ahead i.e. 02:00:00

So all you have to do is

```
// this should pick up the default timezone from the server
$date = new DateTime($row_forum['Date']);
// adjust the timezone you want the output to be in
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Africa/Lagos'));

// get the data and time in whatever format you want to show it as
echo 'It was ' . $date->format('H:i:s') . ' in Lagos';
```

It should not matter where your server is now, or gets moved to sometime later, you will always get the time in Lagos.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose you can use `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` like this:

```
$dt = new DateTime($row_forum['Date'], new DateTimeZone('Africa/Lagos'));
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```